# Javascript execution in Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am a beginer in automated testing, for now I am using only a Selenium IDE recorder.

I am creating a test suite for page that contains a lot of scripts such as calculated values, various data verifications, alerts, cells disabled be scripts on condition

none of those scripts are called when i execute test recorded in Selenium IDE, my actions - simple data entry to cells - script calculates value in another

Also, script disables some cells whn page is loaded, but when a page is loaded with Selenium cells are enabled.

How can I enable scripts from Selenium?

Thanks in advance,

Anna

Comment: The reality is that Selenium IDE (or _any_ record & playback tool) will not get you far in test automation. You will only be able to cover the most basic functionality of your site. More advanced test automation, especially for modern AJAX heavy sites, is very "challenging" with such tools, and your time will be better spent learning a real programming language and something like Selenium-WebDriver.

Comment: thanks, thats where I'm heading

Comment: Try pausing after each selenium command. Use pause for the command and 2000 for the target (2 seconds). This gives the javascript time to calculate and populate values. It may be that your selenium script is executing faster than the javascript.